# Safari GC does not run?

Tags: javascript, safari, garbage-collection

The following [example](https://jsfiddle.net/gvLdr2uz/2/) demonstrates that Safari memory grows infinitely. As you see all the objects inside the `init` function should be cleared after every "reload" button click. But that does not happen. Any idea why? Thanks for the advise!

Comment: Why do you use the TS playground for pure js, which then has 45 errors? Also, i stopped, when you had a `setInterval`, don't store the return, have it call `start` every five seconds, which in turn sets another interval.

Comment: @ASDFGerte thanks for the questions. I agree - all that makes sense and brings confusion. I moved the code into jsfiddle and made example even more easier.